# Applying a patch using git am

Tags: linux, git

I know that there is a way to use git am to apply patches to my commit. I have been using the command patch -pnum < patch_file_name.txt to do so.
So can someone explain please how git am works and do I need to open a mailbox to use this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`git am` applies a patch to your repository. It alters files specified in the patch file and creates a git commit.

`git am` expects a patch file to be formatted in a special way, as an email submission patch. It contains a commit message as well. Patches for `git am` are generated using `git format-patch` command.

Normal patches are generated with `git diff` and will not work with `git am`.

`patch` command understands both diff-file styles. It applies changes from a patch file without doing anything else.

You do not need to open a mailbox to use `git am`.

---

#### A typical patch file for `git am`:

```
From b405aa93926c458a6723c8a2b3d2e768da26350b Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Foo Bar <email@example.com>
Date: Sun, 1 Feb 2015 02:33:35 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] update tasks

---
 TODO.md | 1 ++++
 1 file changed, 1 insertions(+)

diff --git a/TODO.md b/TODO.md
index 9b7aad8..8cb25ce 100644
--- a/TODO.md
+++ b/TODO.md
@@ -8,7 +8,11 @@
   - bar
   - foo
 - [ ] lorem ipsum
+- [ ] lorem dolor

2.2.2
```

#### A diff generated for `patch` / `git apply` command:

```
diff --git a/TODO.md b/TODO.md
index 9b7aad8..8cb25ce 100644
--- a/TODO.md
+++ b/TODO.md
@@ -8,7 +8,11 @@
   - bar
   - foo
 - [ ] lorem ipsum
+- [ ] lorem dolor
```